# Google Drive SDk Connection reset by peer

Tags: java, android, ssl, google-drive-api

I am using following code to load public shared images from google drive to android app, but sometimes I got:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Read error: ssl=0x1d9ed0: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
```

Why google drive is closing connection before I download image? This is happening randomly, but quite often. Does someone collide with such problem?

```
public static InputStream getStream(String url)
{

    InputStream is = null;
    try
    {
        is = new URL(url).openConnection().getInputStream();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        L.e(e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        L.e(e.toString());
    }

    return is;
}
```

For bitmap loading I use simple code:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that you are affected by the following: The URL that you get from the file's metadata is short lived. If you are saving that URL to use later it won't work because it could be that the URL gets invalidated.

To do this you have to fetch the image metadata every time to get the new downloadURL.

We are working on providing non expirable URLs in the future.